# Kendo Upload- Change File Name and get it back

Tags: file-upload, kendo-ui

I use kendo upload on my mvc project. My user have to upload files and I have to change file name with the unique file name. 
I change the file name in the controller :

```js
public ActionResult Dosyayukle(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

            var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), fileName.Replace(ext, "") + Guid.NewGuid() + ext);
            file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
        }
    }

    // Return an empty string to signify success
    return Content("");
}
```

I need to get file name and save this file name to db with unique name.

In JS onComplate event I can't found the file new file name.

```js
this.onComplate = function (e) {

    var dosyaAdi = self.dosyaAdi();
    if (dosyaAdi.match(/rar$/)) {
        alert('rar');
    } else if (dosyaAdi.match(/zip$/)) {
        alert('zip');
    } else {
        alert(dosyaAdi);
    }
};
```

How can I pass the new file name to onComplate event handler?

Or how can I do this another way ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TempData to store key value object in which you can save file name and unique key. The same temp data you can get it in the save call.
Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a solution for your question.

http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/editor/giving-the-uploaded-files-unique-names.aspx

Comment: i found a solution few days ago. I created a unique guid in javascript and in onUpload function i set the parameter like this
        e.data = { basketId: self.basketId(), guid: myGuid };
and save the file this guid name. thanks for your comment